# Espaçamento com o Menu

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Estou o seguinte problema:

Não consigo retirar esse espaçamento do menu com o jumbotron.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="nav$">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="sucesso.php">BW</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="#"><a href="sucesso.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Perguntas</a></li>
            <li><a href="perfil.php">Perfil</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
</nav>

 <div class="jumbotron">   
   <div class="container">
         
                <h1>Bem vindo!</h1>
                <p>Agora você já pode tirar suas dúvidas.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Fazer pergunta</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: este site esta hospedado? assim ta dificil de saber se é margin ou padding...

Comment: Olá @LeonardoMax, upei pra um servidor aqui (http://69.60.115.37/~augustobw/perfil.php). O problema que tinha comentado simplesmente sumiu. Mas por outro lado apareceu um novo..a pagina está com uma rolagem lateral.